# How to redirect output to a file from within cron?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, cron

I have a backup script which I need to run at a particular time of a day so I am using `cron` for this task and from within cron am also trying to redirect the output of backup script to a `logfile`.

`crontab -e`

```
*/1 * * * * /home/ranveer/backup.sh &>> /home/ranveer/backup.log
```

In the above cron entry I am redirecting both `stderr and stdout` to a log file.

The above cron job executes fine according to `syslog`  and it performs the task mentioned in the `backup.sh` file but it doesn't write anything to the log file.

`/var/log/syslog`

```
Oct 19 20:26:01 ranveer CRON[15214]: (ranveer) CMD (/home/ranveer/backup.sh &>> /home/ranveer/backup.log)
```

When I run the script from cli it works as required and output is written to a log file

```
ranveer@ranveer:~$ ./backup.sh &>> backup.log 
ranveer@ranveer:~$ cat backup.log
Fri Oct 19 20:28:01 IST 2012
successfully copied testdir
test.txt successfully copied
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ranveer@ranveer:~$
```

So, why the output of file is not getting redirected to the file from within cron.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/122246/how-can-i-view-results-of-my-cron-jobs

Answer (score 281, accepted):

I solved the problem. There are two ways:

**M1**

Change the redirection from `&>>` to `2>&1`. So now `crontab -e` looks like

```
*/1 * * * * /home/ranveer/vimbackup.sh >> /home/ranveer/vimbackup.log 2>&1
```

**I believe** the above works because by default `cron` is using `sh` to run the task instead of `bash` so `&>>` is not supported by `sh`.

**M2**

Change the default shell by adding `SHELL=/bin/bash` in the `crontab -e` file.

Comment: `cron` is like `sh`: it doesn't pick out a single program. There are many implementations. The most prevalent implementation is Vixie cron. I am the (current, not the original) author of another. I believe that most cron daemons will use the system's `sh`, but that can vary in whether it accepts `&>>`. Some cron daemons (like mine) don't enable you to change which shell executes the cron lines with `SHELL=...` lines in the crontab. I'm glad you found a solution that works for you; just thought it was worth pointing out there are many variables that could affect whether it works for others.

Comment: How to insert `YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-sec` into output file name, so that every file name is different and kept without rewriting?

Comment: @Danijel : This should help http://serverfault.com/questions/117360/sending-cron-output-to-a-file-with-a-timestamp-in-its-name

Comment: `*/1 * * * * /home/ranveer/vimbackup.sh &>> /home/ranveer/vimbackup.log` does the same thing too.

Comment: What is the difference between `>` and `>>` after the command?

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb `>` replaces the contents of the file with the STDOUT from the command, and `>>` appends the file with the output from the command.

Answer (score 11):

disclaimer [1].

I would like to add a footnote or addendum to [@RanRag's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52332/5510).

**Make sure your shell redirection syntax conforms to `/bin/sh`. If you try to use shell redirection syntax that is not valid with `/bin/sh` then your command will fail and your cron job will not ever run.**

In your `/etc/cron.d/example1` config files if you specify a user other than `root` and that user's login shell is not `/bin/bash`... you must still use /bin/sh syntax in `/etc/cron.d/example1` command.

---

### For example

If your user has shell `csh` or `zsh` or `ksh` set for his login shell. In your `/etc/cron.d/example1` config file, the command must use `/bin/sh` syntax. Specifically any shell redirection must be `/bin/sh` syntax.

If you try to use for example `csh` shell redirect syntax in your `/etc/cron.d/example1`, then your cron job will never run. The logfile for `crond` located at `/var/log/cron` shall say that the command is run but the command will error out with a syntax error before your command gets run.

### Where does `crond` emit error messages for a syntax error?

The error is not ever reported in `/var/log/cron`. `crond` instead by default emits any error messages using `mail`. So you must check `/var/spool/mail/${USER}` to see what is the error.

[1]

### Disclaimer

- This answer assumes a `sysv` system
- `systemd` information may differ
- Specifically this information was learned for `centos-6` distro and may not apply to different `sysv` distros

  - I mention `centos-6` specifically, because different distros may have a different `crond` implementation that differs from `centos-6`

Comment: if you wish to have your `/etc/cron.d/example1` command use a different shell, you can use set the `SHELL=` in your `/etc/cron.d/example1` config file.

Answer (score 2):

You can direct output information to a log file with 2 greater-than signs like this example:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/script.py >> /path/to/logfile/output.log
```

Please see this convient crontab-line generator in this link: https://crontab-generator.org/