# Why does this rsync command running in a cron fail?

Tags: linux, cron, rsync, command

**Why does this rsync command running in a cron fail and how to debug it and fix?**

```
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK && unset KRB5CCNAME && rsync -hvru -e "ssh -p 34503 -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa_rsyncBACKUP" --progress /home/kristjan/* kristjan@192.168.1.213:/BACKUP/Backup/Kundrum/ >> /home/kristjan/logs/rsyncCRON.log
```

---

```
$crontab -l
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 5 * * 1 /home/kristjan/bin/checkSystem
00 02 * * * unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK && unset KRB5CCNAME && rsync -hvru -e "ssh -p 34503 -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa_rsyncBACKUP" --progress /home/kristjan/* kristjan@192.168.1.213:/BACKUP/Backup/Kundrum/ >> /home/kristjan/logs/rsyncCRON.log
15 23 * * 7 /home/kristjan/bin/unhideCheckSystem
```

**The error is (which I got from a email):**

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.213 port 34503: No route to host

rsync: connection unexpectedly closed
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c (235)
```

The command works if I run it in the shell directly.

EDIT:

from ssh file on remote = `AllowUsers kristjan root` and cron is run by `root`

EDIT:

Since posting this question I changed the command and it works that way but I'm still interested in knowing why the first didn't work.

Here is the working command in root's cron:

```
0 5 * * 1 /home/kristjan/bin/checkSystem
00 02 * * * unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK && unset KRB5CCNAME && rsync -hvru -e "ssh -p 34503 -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa_rsyncBACKUP" --progress /home/kristjan/* kristjan@192.168.1.213:/BACKUP/Backup/Kundrum/ | mail -s "Backup Home report for `uname -n`" myMailATTgmail.com
```

EDIT because of duplicate flag:

If this was a question about basically doing redirection wrong(not saying I didn't) then why this line in the original question:

```
The command works if I run it in the shell directly.
```

Comment: What's the log / failure?

Comment: @JeffSchaller no such directory or file, my system is Debian Stretch all updates

Comment: @JeffSchaller email says `no route to host`

Comment: In a previous comment, you first said that you got a "no such file or directory" error. That error should have included 1) what program generated it, and 2) what file was not found. Could you say something about this?

Comment: @Kusalananda no thats a mistake I did because  I thought the comment before was asking með to check log/failure logfile

Comment: I'm noticing that the port number mentioned in the error is not the port number that you're trying to connect to.

Comment: Sorry should have left it as it was

Comment: The IP's don't line up, either; the rsync says it's connecting to 192.168.1.213 but the error message mentions 192.168.1.19.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Sorry should have left it as it was –

Comment: which user of remote host is authenticated to connect from local host? which user's crontab you are running rsync from?

Comment: @αғsнιη from ssh file on remote = `AllowUsers kristjan root` and cron is run by `root`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect output to a file from within cron?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52330/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-from-within-cron)

Comment: The possible duplicate is asking about output redirection using Bash-specific operators in a cron job. However, this question is not using Bash-isms, just the regular POSIX append operator, `>>`.