# Why this script doesn't work from cron while it works when invoke from my shell?

Tags: shell-script, cron, variable, rm

The following code does work when invoked from my shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

how_many=$(find /home/jerzy/pCloudDrive -type d -iname "CS202*"|wc -l)
#/usr/bin/echo ${how_many} >>/home/jerzy/to.be.removed #This works

if [[ $how_many == 1 ]]; then

 exit 0
 #echo "There is only one backup of CS. Cannot delete."

elif [[ $how_many == 2 ]]; then

 exit 0
 #echo "There are only two backups of CS. Cannot delete."
else

 #echo "Let us delete"
 
 to_be_removed=$(ls -tr CS202*|grep -m 1 CS202|sed s/://)
 
 /usr/bin/echo "${to_be_removed}" >>/home/jerzy/to.be.removed #empty file is created from cron
 /usr/bin/echo "$(ls -tr CS202*|grep -m 1 CS202|sed s/://)" >>/home/jerzy/to.be.removed #empty file is created from cron
 #/usr/bin/echo ${to_be_removed} >>/home/jerzy/to.be.removed #empty file is created from cron
 #/usr/bin/echo \$\{to_be_removed\} >>/home/jerzy/to.be.removed #"${to_be_removed}" appended from cron
 /usr/bin/echo "${to_be_removed}" #when the script is run from my shell it echoes the target directory 
 
/usr/bin/rm -r ${to_be_removed} #works from the shell, not from cron
 #/usr/bin/rm -r $(ls -tr CS202*|grep -m 1 CS202|sed s/://) ##works from the shell, not from cron
 #/usr/bin/rm -r "${to_be_removed}" 
 

fi
```

The script is meant to remove the oldest directory that is named like one of them :

```
CS20210730_1341
CS20210730_2350
CS20210731_2350
```

The job is to be done once a day, as each day a new `CS202*` gets created
by rsync doing my backups.
The lines with `echo` are placed in the script only for the sake of debugging.
The code needs **not** `sudo` to remove the specified directory.
It does not work from `cron`, i.e. from the crontab of my user `jerzy`. When executed from the shell of the same user it does the job, why so?

My environmental variables in my cron:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/jerzy/.cargo/bin

SHELL=/bin/bash
```

I've diagnosed so far:

- `rm` does work from cron as `/usr/bin/rm -r /home/jerzy//pCloudDrive/CS20210730_1341` when scripted
  does remove the target. It is not the matter of permissions.
- The execution of the script does get started as is proved by
  the creation of the file `/home/jerzy/to.be.removed`.

Why doesn't this script work from cron?

Comment: You appear to `find` files in `/home/jerzy/pCloudDrive` but then `ls -tr CS202*` in the current working directory

Comment: Why `/usr/bin/echo "${to_be_removed}" >> ...` instead of `/usr/bin/echo "$to_be_removed >> ..."` ?

Comment: You can always send the cron ouput to a log file, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52330/190343) for example. In fact it's always a good idea to keep a log even when you don't have immediate debugging needs. Also check the **exit codes** from your commands. If you have a non-zero return value you should probably not continue.

Comment: @steeldriver Replacing `ls -tr CS202*` with `ls -tr /home/jerzy/pCloudDrive/CS202*` solved the issue. It had nothing to do with cron. It was just a coincidence the I was always invoking the program from `/home/jerzy/pCloudDrive` - it do not work from other directories, though.

Comment: @Jeremy The first is meant to append the path of the directory to be removed to the file - so that I there is anything appended I know that until this point the script works fine. What would the second do?

Comment: Point taken -;)